# Question about polynomial irreducibility

Tags: ring-theory

I was looking if $X^4 + 2$  was irreducible in $\mathbb{R} \left[  X\right] $, $\mathbb{Q} \left[  X\right] $ and $\mathbb{Z_{7}} \left[  X\right] $. It's easy to prove that in $\mathbb{R} \left[  X\right] $ is irreducible due to the fact that has $2$ complex roots.

The previous reason is applicable for $\mathbb{Q} \left[  X\right] $, but in $\mathbb{Z_{7}} \left[  X\right] $ I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ you have that $x^4+2=(x^2+\sqrt{2})^2-2\sqrt{2}x^2=(x^2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{2}x)(x^2+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{2}x)$

Comment: Do you really want to work over the 7-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_7$ or are you thinking about $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{F}_7$?  They are related when you further reduce mod 7 or use Hensel to lift in the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $\mathbb{Z}_7$, notice that $$X^4+2=(X^2+X+4)(X^2-X+4)$$

Comment: Did you mean $(X^\color{red}2-X+4)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you very much, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that all roots are complex does not imply irreducibility. In this case, that polynomial can be written as a product of two quadratics over $\Bbb R$

The only polynomials irreducible over $\Bbb R$ is of degree one or two, since $[\Bbb C : \Bbb R]=2$, so your polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb R$

Eisenstein criterion shows it is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$

Comment: Add a space between the final b and Q !

Comment: Yes! Thanks......